# how can select multiple rows from gridview and store in array in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, gridview, checkbox

I wrote code for asp.net c#

I use grid view  to display information from database and I am using checkbox to select the data , but the problem How can save these data I selected in array , then save it to data base .

this my code

> the grid view

```
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Q_ID" DataField="Q_Multiple_ID" />

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="The Question" DataField="Multiple_Question" />




            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

> the c#

protected void GetSelectedRecords(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    string selected = "";
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)

        {

            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");


        // get the selected AutoId and cells text
        if (chk.Checked)
            {

            string QID = GridView3.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex].Values["Q_Multiple_ID"].ToString();
            selected += QID;
            test.Text = selected;


        }
    }

    test.Text = selected;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

> c#

protected void GetSelectedRecords(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    string [] array = new string[6];

    int count = 0;

    string selected = "";

    string QID;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)
        {

        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");


        // get the selected AutoId and cells text
        if (chk.Checked)
            {
            count += 1;

         QID = GridView3.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex].Values["Q_Multiple_ID"].ToString();
            selected += QID;

           if(count <= 5)
            {
                array[count] = QID;


                Response.Write(array[5]);
            }
            else
            {
                chk.Checked = false;
            }

        }
        test.Text = selected;
    }



}
```